# Use import keyword without Babel in Node 6

Tags: node.js, module, babeljs

I am wondered why Node.js `node index.js` raises the following error :

```
   (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import * as math from "lib/math";
                                                          ^^^^^^
        SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
            at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:456:3
```

Even , `node -v` shows `6.2.1` .

## Does `import` keywords is restricted with Babel , even we use Node 6 (6.2.1)  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ES 2015 Modules (and therefore the `import` keyword) are not supported by default in Node.js v6.

You can enable experimental (and almost certainly buggy) module support by launching `node` with the `--harmony_modules` flag.

A better option might be to use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or a similar tool to transpile ES 2015 modules.

Or you can rewrite your code to not use ES 2015 modules at all.